# How to set TCP_CORK option in Java code

Tags: java, tcp, nio

I'm using java 7, java nio to build my application. I don't know how to set TCP_CORK option in java code.
I just see TCP_NODELAY, SO_SNDBUF... options.
Please tell me how.
Thank you

Comment: You can't. It's platform-specific, to Linux I believe.

Comment: I don't believe we can't. At least, C++ or Netty support to set TCP_CORK option, my problem is I'm using java nio

Comment: You've *been* helped. What part of "you can't" don't you understand?

Comment: "You belive" or you're sure, it is not the same....?Are you confident of your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `TCP_CORK` is a Linux specific socket option and not specified by e.g. POSIX. It's therefore platform specific and not available in Java.